# Facebook API recently updated status messages

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is there any method in the Facebook API that will return the status messages of the most recently updated accounts (similar to the GetPublicTimeline method from Twitter's API)? To be a little more specific, I'm planning on using Python to do the data retrieval, and I was wondering if there was a way to get the Public Timeline using PyFacebook or minifb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, not yet. They haven't indicated that they will either.

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed to know.